# How to remove "concave" hex oil drain plug?

Tags: oil-change, bolts, drain

I am quite handy but I've never bothered to try my own car maintenance. But I want to start with oil changes so I know how. After crawling under my 2008 Subaru Impreza and finding the oil drain plug I noticed that it wasn't simply a normal hex head bolt but rather a "reverse" or "concave" head, I've never seen this before. How am I supposed to remove it, I don't even know what to search for to buy. I tried to find a close photo of something similar as shown below.

[image]

Comment: standard hex or allen socket  not to plug a particular brand bu here is a pic http://www.sears.com/craftsman-6-pc-metric-3-8-in-dr/p-00934448000P?sid=SLIAx125x101&sid=isx20140327xdsa&psid=601x39989&knshCrid=195956063903&k_clickID=a6a9d50a-62c8-4f55-968b-e26f3429e3a8&gclid=Cj0KEQjwmcTJBRCYirao6oWPyMsBEiQA9hQPbuTVha2LytTYZIEIMEo-FFD9-kf131SdbwX5wNKPwRoaAiQj8P8HAQ

Comment: A simple allen key will also work. Saves on buying a set of allen sockets, but that might be a good investment...

Comment: That would be a metric Allen wrench!